# iOS 6 NSDateFormatter stringFromDate: empty day of week

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nsdateformatter, dayofweek

I'm having an issue with obtaining the full name for the day of week in iOS 6 NSDate object (in iOS 7 works fine).
I've searched stackoverflow for similar issues but I didn't find what I was looking for.

My test case is:

```
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
[formatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:NO];

NSDate *testDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1384551041.389218];
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:testDate]);
```

The expected output is `Friday` (localized to your device region format and on a gregorian calendar), it works on iOS 7 but on iOS 6 it returns an empty description. I've tested in actual devices with the same region format set.

As far as I know, iOS 6 uses [tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) formatting according to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html), and the `EEEE` specifies full name day of week in that format.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That actually looks like a bug in `NSDateFormatter` on iOS 6. However, it seems that
the bug occurs only if you explicitly set

```
[formatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:NO];
```

If you omit that line (and `NO` is the default anyway) then the result is OK (at least when I tested it).

*Remark:* I assume that `setDoesRelativeDateFormatting` is only meant to be used in connection
with `setDateStyle:`, but that is pure guessing.

Comment: What will be the alternative then??

Comment: @hussainShabbir: As I said, just omit the `setDoesRelativeDateFormatting` call.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove [formatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:NO]; from your code then you will get the result in both iOS 6.0 and iOS 7.0